# Is It Possibly to Change the Type of Control in Code Behind

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, user-controls, custom-controls

I am interesting in knowing if there is a way to change the type of control that is being displayed in the View in the code behind. For instance, there is a list of Buttons in the view but I would like to change all of the buttons to HubTiles on a button click event. Right now I only have my buttons being generated by XAML, and I actually have them in a panorama control like the following

MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <controls:Panorama Title="my application">

        <!--Panorama item one-->
        <controls:PanoramaItem Header="item1">
            <Button X:Name="button1" Content="button 1" Click="button1_Click"/>
            <Button X:Name="button2" Content="button 2" Click="button2_Click"/>
            <Button X:Name="button3" Content="button 3" Click="button3_Click"/>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>

        <!--Panorama item two-->
        <controls:PanoramaItem Header="item2">
            <Button X:Name="button4" Content="button 4" Click="button4_Click"/>
            <Button X:Name="button5" Content="button 5" Click="button5_Click"/>
            <Button X:Name="button6" Content="button 6" Click="button6_Click"/>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>
    </controls:Panorama>
</Grid>
```

Is there a way to not only generate these buttons in code behind (each one will of course perform a certain action) but also be able to switch the control type to a HubTile, say from a SettingsPage ListPicker (with two items, buttons or tiles)?

Comment: I think the easiest solution is to make a custom control (or usercontrol) that allows you to switch from Button to HubTile by setting a property. Then you can bind this property on all your controls to the same source, and switch all of them at once

Comment: Ok, so how exactly would I go about doing that though. Honestly I've never tried something like this before so I'm not sure where to even start. I know how to create a user control in my application and use it within my MainPage, but as for creating the ability to have a button and hubtile and switch between them is where I am confused.

Comment: Add them both to your usercontrol, and use the `Visibility` property to display one or another